# NavEE include_single_parent will not work when no kids exist

Tags: navee

I have the following code.

```
<nav class="nav nav--secondary">
{exp:navee:custom 
    nav_title="primary"
    parent_selected_class="is-current"
    selected_class="is-current"
    selected_class_on_parents="true"
    start_nav_from_parent="true"
    start_nav_from_parent_depth="2"
    display_all_children_of_selected="true"
    include_single_parent="true"
    wrap_type="ol"
}

    <li class="nav__item">
        <a href="{link}" class="nav__link {class}">
            {text}
            <i class="icn icn--arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        {if has_kids}<div class="nav nav--tertiary">{kids}</div>{/if}
    </li>

{/exp:navee:custom}
```

EE v2.5.5
NavEE v2.2.7

The outcome I am aiming for is: display selected nav item and kids of selected nav item. Everything is working great unless the selected nav item has no kids. When that happens, nothing appears. When the selected nav item has kids, the selected nav will show along with the kids. I have this exactly how I want it to behave except I can't get the selected nav to show up when it does not have kids. I would appreciate any input on this matter. Also happy to clarify if needed.

Here are the two pages:
[Displaying nav items properly (it has kids)](http://www.f35.com.epi.qa/global/participation/australia)
[Not displaying nav at all (it has no kids)](http://www.f35.com.epi.qa/global/participation/denmark)

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you remove/alter either {start_nav_from_parent="true"} or {start_nav_from_parent_depth="2"}

It's not even adding the  on the page without children (just thinking outloud)....

Comment: When I remove {start_nav_from_parent="true"}, it displays the entire site navigation. Then, when I remove {start_nav_from_parent_depth="2"}, it shows the same thing.